# php Replacing multiple spaces with a single space

Tags: php, regex, formatting, string-formatting, ereg-replace

I'm trying to replace multiple spaces with a single space. When I use `ereg_replace`, I get an error about it being deprecated.

```
ereg_replace("[ \t\n\r]+", " ", $string);
```

Is there an identical replacement for it. I need to replace multiple `" "` white spaces and multiple `nbsp` white spaces with a single white space.

Answer (score 480, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and instead of `[ \t\n\r]` use `\s`:

```
$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);
```

From [Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html):

> \d, \w and \s
>
> Shorthand character classes matching
>   digits, word characters (letters,
>   digits, and underscores), and
>   whitespace (spaces, tabs, and line
>   breaks). Can be used inside and
>   outside character classes.

Comment: @Cletus: This one would replace a single space with space. Don't you think something like: preg_replace('/(?:\s\s+|\n|\t)/', ' ', $x) will be more *efficient* especially on text with several single spaces ?

Comment: @codaddict: by chance, a moment ago i benchmarked those on real-life data, result (for calls on ~8300 various text articles): `/(?:\s\s+|\n|\t)/` => 1410 (slowest), `/\s+/` => 611 (ok'ish), `/\s\s+/` => 496 (fastest). The last one does not replace single `\n` or `\t`, but thats ok for my case.

Comment: /\s{2,}/u' - if you have some UTF-8 problem add /u switch

Comment: for unicode there is `mb_ereg_replace` [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php)

Comment: @cletus , great work!, with keeping this regex pattern, is there a way to get rid of all spaces at the right & and the left of the string? for example,
"      a          b           c        ", would be "a b c",
I know we could use trim($output), but it would be nice to have it in regex

Comment: This does not work; did any of the nearly 400 people test this code with an input string that contained three or more consecutive spaces? ︎

Comment: This should not be correct answer, as it removes all the newlines as well, question is about spaces...

Comment: I'm not sure what the exclamation marks do but a quick Google shows that they do something like limit the number of matches. So as a previous comment says, maybe this matches a maximum of three spaces which might negate the use of +. 
That said, I have just tested with three and four spaces and it works correctly for me.
Can anyone explain exactly what the exclamation marks do? Are they preferable to forward slashes?

Answer (score 82):

```
$output = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$input);
```

`\s` is shorthand for `[ \t\n\r]`. Multiple spaces will be replaced with single space.

Answer (score 53):

```
preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$input)
```

Comment: Doesn't replace "\n" (PHP 5.3), "/\s+/" get's job done. ;)

Comment: Actually this helped, \s messed up my multibyte word, replaceing Š with some kind of square.

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis There is separate multibyte function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php

Comment: Unlike other answers, this command only replaces spaces (not newlines, etc...), which is exactly what is needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: The code for multibyte encoding would be `mb_ereg_replace('[[:blank:]]+', ' ', $input)`or `mb_ereg_replace('\s+', ' ', $input)` depending on the use case.