# pleas help me with php trim function

Tags: php, sql, mysql

trim function delete all more spaces but when try to save data in database it was save with more spaces why pleas help me i but down all code and database construction to help be

```
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`user` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`username` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

////////////////////////
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$conn){
        die("there is problem in" .mysql_error());
    }
    $select_db = mysql_select_db("test",$conn);
    if(!$select_db){
        die("there is problem in" .mysql_error());
    }
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $fname = trim($_POST["text"]);
    $name = trim($fname);
    $insert = mysql_query("insert into user(username)values('{$name}')");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should show us the data you're using, and the results your getting. Also, never put unescaped data in a query.

Comment: I'm under the impression you think that trim removes spaces within the word instead of just before/after.

Comment: Note: there is no purpose to trimming your data twice `$fname = trim($_POST["text"]); $name = trim($fname);`. Just do `$name = trim($_POST["text"]);`

Answer (score 3):

The `trim` function only removes leading and trailing spaces, not double spaces *within* the text. You can use `preg_replace` for that, e.g.:

```
$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);
```

Source: [php Replacing multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Comment: wow thanks could u pleas tell me name of the book or site learn me regular exp?

Comment: A great place to start is by watching the [Regular Expressions for Dummies](http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/regular-expressions-for-dummies/) screencast (here are [parts 2-5](http://blog.themeforest.net/?s=regex+for+dummies)). There's also a good tutorial on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), and you can easily test regex online with [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler than using regex

```
$without_spaces = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST["text"]);
```