# Comparison page content

Tags: php, email

I need script that sends me email when something changes on page.
This is my code but it's not working correct. How can i do this to work properly?

```
$new_page = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

$new_page_in = mysql_real_escape_string($new_page);
mysql_query("UPDATE new SET text='$new_page_in' WHERE id='1'") or die (mysql_error());

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM new WHERE id='1'") or die (mysql_error());
list($new_out) = mysql_fetch_row($sql1);

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM old WHERE id='1'") or die (mysql_error());
list($old_out) = mysql_fetch_row($sql2);    

if($new_out != $old_out)
{
    $new_page = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
    $new_page_in = mysql_real_escape_string($new_page);
    mysql_query("UPDATE old SET text='$new_page_in' WHERE id='1'") or die (mysql_error());
    echo "Text is diferent.";
            //send email
}
else
{
    echo "Text isn't diferent";
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is never a sufficient problem description. Please explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Stay in the first if where is the "Text is diferent."

Comment: Which language is this? PHP? Please add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the comparison

```
strcmp($new_out, $old_out) == 0
```

to test if they are the same.

Also I would suggest just storing a hash of the page content in the database instead of the entire string. So store

```
hash('md5', $new_page)
```

in the database instead of `$new_page` and compare hashes if you want to see if anything has changed. Store the content as well if you need to, but don't compare on the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest while storing the htmlcontent add `htmlentities` and also remove all the whitespaces before before storing....
You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space) for the regex to do the same....

Also you can make use of the string algorithms like [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) or [similar-text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) to check the matching percentage and keep some threshold maybe 95% for almost same