# Normalize spaces in a string?

Tags: php

I need to normalize the spaces in a string:

1. Remove multiple adjacent spaces
2. Remove spaces at the beginning and end of the string

E.g. `"  my name    is   "` => `my name is`

I tried

```
str_replace('  ',' ',$str);
```

I also tried [php Replacing multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space) but that didn't work either.

Comment: The RegExp solution you linked seems like a fine solution. Why do you think it's not helpful to you?

Comment: ***How*** is that referenced question ***not*** helpful for your needs?

Comment: i also want to remove space before and after string.. referenced code remove duplicate spaces and its different from my question

Comment: didn't you tried any one? preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$input)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php Replacing multiple spaces with a single space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 14):

Replace any occurrence of 2 or more spaces with a single space, and trim:

```
$str = preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', trim($input));
```

Note: using the whitespace character class `\s` here is a fairly bad idea since it will match linebreaks and other whitespace that you might not expect.

Comment: Don't forget OP needs to trim spaces at the beginning and end of line. Updated the answer :) Also, if the real task is to replace all "whitespace" symbols: space, tab, vertical tab (anybody seen that ever?), etc. use `\s` instead of just ` `

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex

```
$text = preg_replace("~\\s{2,}~", " ", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\s` approach strips away newlines too, and `/ {2,}/` approach ignores tabs and spaces at beginning of line right after a newline.

If you want to save newlines and get a more accurate result, I'd suggest [this impressive answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469155/214517), and [this improvement of the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17752989/214517). According to their note, the answer to your question is:

```
$norm_str = preg_replace('/[^\S\r\n]+/', ' ', trim($str));
```

In short, this is taking advantage of double negation. Read the links to get an in-depth explanation of the trick.