# replacing spaces with just one "_"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to replace all of the consecutive spaces with just **one** underscore; I can easily replace one space with "_" by using the following line of code:

```
str_replace(" ", "_",$name);
```

Evan I can replace one spaces with "_" by following line of code:

```
str_replace("  ", "_",$name);
```

But the problem is I don't know how many blank spaces I have to check!

If my question is not clear please let me know which part you need more clarification.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [php Replacing multiple spaces with a single space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the cleanest and most readable solution:

```
preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', '_', $name);
```

This will replace all spaces (no matter how many) with a single underscore.

Comment: This will replace spaces with dashes, not underscores.

Comment: can also use  preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $name);

Comment: @xlordt Except that'd also replace tabs and line breaks.

Comment: Correct, but who knows.. maybe he will come back and realize that this is what he needed lol.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with a regular expression:

```
[ ]+
```

This will match "one or more space characters"; if you want "any whitespace" (including tabs), you can instead use `\s+`.

Using this with PHP's [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$name = preg_replace('/[ ]+/', '_', $name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace):

```
$name = preg_replace('/ +/', '_', $name);
```

`+` in regex means "repeated 1 or more times" hence this will match `[SPACE]` as well as `[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
$name = preg_replace("#\s+#", "_", $name);
```