# Php replace multiple spaces with single spaces

Tags: php, regex

How can I add something to replace all multiple spaces in a string, with only single spaces in the below regex?. Everything else in the below code needs to remain as it is. I'm only trying to add the replace multiple spaces part.

The other part in there replaces multiple hyphens with a single one.

```
$name = preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', $rawName);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php Replacing multiple spaces with a single space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Comment: Did you see this ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326125/remove-multiple-whitespaces-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)

```
$name = preg_replace('#\s+#', ' ', $rawName);
```

Comment: Actually, I was asking how to add this to the existing code I have. Now it seems all my hyphens are missing. So I did this: `echo preg_replace('#[ -\s]+#','-',$rawName);` but is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: @jmenezes `$name = preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', $rawName);` will replace all spaces to hyphen. Your question was how to replace multiple spaces to one. Put the answer line posted above, the `$name = preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', $rawName);` line.

Comment: You got two things to do. 1. Replace all multispaces to one and 2. Replace all spaces to hyphen. Right?

Comment: @jmenezes If thats the case, can you please try this one only replacing the line you got there - `$name = preg_replace('#\s+#', '-', $rawName);`

Comment: The solution in your second comment works nicely. Just one small question, is it ok to do it the way I posted in my first comment?

Comment: @jmenezes : It will work. Actually the method you used in first place also need to work. But keep in mind that what you put inside the `[]` brackets inside a regex is character set. So it will match it as characters except the characters with \ . `'#[-\s]+#'` will work. You need to only use `[ ]` or `[\s]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
that should kee only one space between words

```
{
 $var = str_replace(' ','',$var);
}
```

Comment: that would only reduce one space from each group and all the single spaces will vanish!...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = preg_replace( "/\s+/", " ", $data );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);
```