# How to trim charachter DEL(ASCII code 127) in PHP

Tags: php, ascii

I trim post value after form submitted, like this:

```
$value=trim($_POST['submit_value']);
```

So if I submit `' some_value '`, then it will become `'some_value'`

[PHP trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) works fine so far.

But recently, there is an DEL(ASCII code 127) character submitted and I don't know how to trim it.

```
$asd=DEL(ASCII code 127) character;
    // I cannot copy, because stackoverflow remove it.
    // it looks like space but it's not. trim() doesn't work. 

echo ord($asd); //return 127
```

any ideas? many thanks!

---

btw, here is a way to type this character:

[Unicode Character 'DELETE' (U+007F)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7f/index.htm)

[How to type in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)

I don't know under what condition will a user need to type this character when register his name

Comment: https://eval.in/840055 check this its return `0` value

Comment: sorry the character has been removed by StackOverflow

Comment: it's the code 127 DEL in [ASCii table](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

It matches anything in range 0-31, 127-255 and removes it.

The answer is from:
[PHP: How to remove all non printable characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string)

---

BTW, one may replace multiple spaces with a single space:

```
$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);
```

[php Replacing multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need only alphanumeric data in this field. than you can do some thing like below code.

```
trim(preg_replace('/[^da-z0-9A-Z]/i', '', $_POST['submit_value']));
```

Comment: thank you,but it works only on English,not on other languages