# How can I trim/remove spaces from in between of a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a string like "Tom  Jerry ". I want to trim the extra space from middle of the string(there is 2 white space between first name and last name, I want only one white space). I.e. desirable output is "Tom Jerry". How do I do that?

Comment: `preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim("Tom  Jerry "))`

Comment: See link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = "Tom  Jerry";
$cleanStr = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $str)));
echo $cleanStr;
```