# Explode() function not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, explode

This might be an easy thing to fix but i still have to ask because it should not be happening in the first place.

I have this simple string:  `24.00C 48%`

Now when using the `explode()` function on this string it should return an Array with 2 Elements.

```
$str = "24.00C 48%";
$str_array = explode(" ", $str);
```

**Expected Result**

`$str_array[0] = 24.00C`
`$str_array[1] = 48%`

**What actually happens**

The first element of the array is correct and it contains what it should (`24.00C`) now the second element of the array was empty so i checked what the array actually contains using `print_r`

Now what it returned is what confuses me the most.

```
Array ( [0] => 24.00C [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => 48% )
```

As you can see the first element is fine but after that its not really doing what it should..

**Now my questions are:**

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to make `explode` work properly?

Also why is the `48%` the 7th Element and not the 3rd as example is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: you have hidden whitespace characters. Try doing `explode(' ', trim($str))`

Comment: @treyBake nothing changed same result

Comment: @treyBake `trim` won't help as the hidden whitespace is inside the string, not on the ends.

Comment: What do you get when you run the split for `$str_array = preg_split("/\s+/", $str);` where `\s+` matches 1+ whitespace characters.

Comment: @Nick huh, didn't know that ^.^ though, in this case, is that still irrelevant? o.O (as in if it's either side of the string, surely we'd see elements either side of the actual values in the explode?

Comment: Quick fix: `array_filter(explode(" ", $str))`

Comment: @Thefourthbird that actually just fixed it ^-^ thank you... but just woundering now is it possible to remove the whitespaces to make `explode` work?

Comment: @Justinas i mean you answer does what it should but the "second" element is the the 7th element of the array...

Comment: `explode(" ", str_replace("C", "C ", str_replace(" ","", "24.00C 48%"))); ` would work to remove all the white space and put back a single space after C, then explode, but it's ugly code

Comment: @Freddy789 FWIW, I just ran your two lines and I got the correct result. I'm going to follow this question to see what the story is.

Comment: @Freddy789 Try to replace if exist any white spaces like this `$str = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $str);` after that `$array=explode(" ", $str);` Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: @dazed-and-confused the two lines is the end of a bunch of ugly `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()` i assume in that process some whitespaces made their way into the string

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is that space is between your string, but perhaps copying that and paste it as the delimiter in explode and see if it works. I would not recommend that though, as you are not really sure what is so you can not rely on it. Using `explode(" ", preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $str))` would be overkill as you could use the preg_split variant. Note that `\s` would also match a newline. So perhaps using `\h` to match horizontal whitespace chars would be better `$str_array = preg_split("/\h+/", $str);`

Comment: @Thefourthbird using \h does the job perfectly fine aswell... and yes i agree using `explode(" ", preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $str))` would be too much but its still intresting to play around with all the possible solutions^^ also i just want to say thanks everyone for your quick responses really helped me learn something new and useful today :)

Comment: @Thefourthbird if you want to write an answer with your solution so i can accept it also for other people with a simular problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistaken on how to print, it should work properly.

Code:

```
$str = "24.00C 48%";
$str_array = explode(" ", $str);

echo $str_array[0] . "<br>";
echo $str_array[1] . "<br>";

print_r($str_array);
```

Result:

```
24.00C
48%
Array ( [0] => 24.00C [1] => 48% )
```

Comment: As i said in the comments the string is build by using loads of `replace` function and during that process some whitespaces made their way into the string. The solution from @the fourth bird `$str_array = preg_split("/\s+/", $str)` solves the problem perfectly