# Replacing spaces only between words with a hyphen and remove all other spaces

Tags: php, regex

How is it possible to remove all spaces but have a hyphen between words, especially when there are spaces at the beginning or end of the string?

For example:

```
"   Cow jumped   over the moon    "
```

should be:

```
"Cow-jumped-over-the-moon"
```

I tried the below but I'm not sure how to get rid of the spaces without hyphens before and after the string.

```
$string_with_dashes = str_replace(' ','-',$string);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php Replacing multiple spaces with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space). `preg_replace("/\s+/", "-", trim($string))`

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks - it answers a part of the question - not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you try the code? Looks like this produces the same output you want to me, `trim` the head and tail and `preg_replace` with `/\s+/`.

Comment: So modify the code in the answer it to fit your needs. It does what you ask.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I see... Perfect - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could trim the `$string` first

```
$string = " Cow jumped over the moon ";
$string_with_dashes = str_replace(' ','-',trim($string));
echo $string_with_dashes;
```

If you want to reduce multiple spaces between the words you can match 1+ horizontal whitespaces `\h+` the replace those with a hyphen.

```
$string_with_dashes = preg_replace("/\h+/", "-", trim($string));
```

Comment: Sounds good!!! But what if there are two or three spaces withing the string. e.g. 3 spaces between `over` and `the`?

Comment: In that case you can explode the string like:

$stringArray = explode(" ", $string); /// it'll became a string.
$joinedString = join("-", $stringArray);

And after that implement the solution above