# How to delete multiple spaces in .txt from PHP

Tags: php

[this is my txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGiDn.png)

I'm adding data from .txt to database with this code:

```html
$dosya=new SplFileObject('veriler.txt');
while(!$dosya->eof())
{
    $satir=$dosya ->fgets();
    list($name,$section,$initialname)=explode(' ',$satir);
     
   $sth= $baglan->prepare('INSERT INTO tablo1 values (NULL,?,?,?,NULL)');
    $sth->bindValue(1,$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(2,$section,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindValue(3,$initialname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
     
}
```

In the .txt if there is a 1 space between the words, my program is working. But as you can see, there are more than one space in my txt file. How can i delete/remove multiple spaces in .txt file? If you can show me in my codes, i will be glad. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368539/php-replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression as well to archive the same result.

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$string = "This  has    too  many spaces";
$result = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", ' ', $string);
echo($result);
?>
```

Where `/\s{2,}/` means after 2 spaces replace it with a single space also consider that `\s` also means any of the following characters:

- \r
- \n
- \t
- \f
- \v
- (empty space)

Link: https://paiza.io/projects/M6eSG1zHIUdG5IZEXFZQog

> \s stands for “whitespace character”. Again, which characters this actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. In all flavors discussed in this tutorial, it includes [ \t\r\n\f]. That is: \s matches a space, a tab, a carriage return, a line feed, or a form feed.

You can read more about this over here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: Might want to use `\h` instead to match only for horizontal whitespaces. Depends on what he wants to do with newlines, though. Also a small nitpick, according to regular-expressions.info, `\s` doesn't match the entirety of `\v`, but only `\r`, `\n` and `\f`(form feed character).

Comment: Thanks I think that's a great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` the string, remove array elements with whitespace, and `implode()`:

```
<?php
    $string = "This  has    too  many spaces";
    $array = explode(" ", $string);
    $array = array_filter($array); 
    $result = implode(" ", $array);
    echo($result);
?>
```

https://paiza.io/projects/Bi-2H7HiPIklLwXGfYAqCg

Comment: So in OPs case this would be `list($name,$section,$initialname)=array_filter(explode(' ',$satir));`?

Comment: They're better off splitting it into a few lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the string it's working, but i want to replace my .txt file and all of words should be 1 space.   I am an amateur in the php, sorry for my easy question

Answer (score 0):

@Crisoforo Gaspar solution in your code :

```
    $dosya=new SplFileObject('veriler.txt');
while(!$dosya->eof())
{
    $satir=$dosya ->fgets();
    $satirWithoutManySpaces = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", ' ', $satir);
    list($name,$section,$initialname)=explode(' ',$satirWithoutManySpaces);

   $sth= $baglan->prepare('INSERT INTO tablo1 values (NULL,?,?,?,NULL)');
    $sth->bindValue(1,$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(2,$section,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindValue(3,$initialname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();

}
```

Hope this help

Comment: it's not working, my .txt file is: https://prnt.sc/s1ag10  ,  when i write your codes, it is added database like this: https://prnt.sc/s1ael5   ,

Comment: You're right, i make a mistake. I think you should use @Crisoforo solution on your $satir var, and after you can use explode function. This should work as expected. I edit my answer